# Microsoft Windows Web Server 2008 + Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Web Edition

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance, sql

I am a totally rookie in this area.

I am about to rent a Dedicated Server, that has Microsoft Windows Web Server 2008 installed in it.

The plan is to put a web application that we have developed in it. But for this web application, we need Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Web Edition. I have read somewhere that both are compatible… but I am not sure. So I would like to have some confirmation on this subject if possible.

Also, in the description of this server, it says: “Windows Server 2008 Web Edition (1 processor)”. This obviously means that it only uses 1 processor… I didn’t know that could be applied to Windows itself… I thought it was just the SQL Server (since the license is Per Processor). Is this some typo? Or the Windows Web Server is Per Processor too?
Also, performance wise, am I choosing the right Windows Server and SQL Server versions? (I remember you, that this is a Web Application developed by us). I think that other distributions of Windows Server and SQL Server are only a matter of features, and not performance… right?

*PS: I know, I know… too many questions on a single post. But if you think that is more correct to create multiple questions…. I can do that.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- They are compatible.
- No, it means that the price is for one processor. These are licensed per processor. You HAVE to license as many processors as the server has. For both.
- All are per processor. This is how SPLA licensing works. For that they are - cheap ;) And no CAL.
- Try using expres edition if money is an issue. otherwise - you will see when you run into an issue. The next REAL step up would be Enterprise server for SQL - vey expensive. Performance depends a LOT on hardware (disc subsystem - do NOT go with less than 2 drive SETS to start with) and exact programming / requirements.

I have seen servers vomit on 2 requests per second - because idiot programmers put in no indices. It really depends. SQL Server is really high performane ,b ut SQL Server REALLY depends on how you use it and what you need IO wise.

NOTE: If this is a start for you, check MS BizSpark initiative - quite a lot of low cost stuff for the first three years.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But you said: "You HAVE to license as many processors as the server has". And on their website the processor says: "1x Intel Quad Core Xeon X3210", and the software says: "Windows Server 2008 Web Edition (1 processor)". Does this means that the other 3 cores won't be used?!!!!

Comment: It says PROCESSOR, not CORE. Ms was the first to say "a physical processor is one SOCKET, regardless how many cores".

Comment: Great! Thank you a lot for your comments. I would give you extra points but I need 15 points to "mark has usefull". Once again, thank you.